# Difference between To and In

Tags: prepositions

"Have you ever been to the US?"
Why in this question is "to" instead of "in".
What is the difference between that prepositions?

Comment: "To" is generally a preposition of *direction*.  "In" is generally a preposition of *location*.   The difference is simply asking whether you have *traveled* there, or *been in* there.

Comment: @Andrew: That sounds like an answer I would upvote.

Comment: @sharur  perhaps but the question is just basic grammar and should probably be closed, especially since it lacks any detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To" is generally a preposition of direction. "In" is generally a preposition of location. The difference is simply asking whether you have traveled there, or been in there. -- Andrew.

Comment: James, very good answer and I like the way of expression.